# how to generate flowchart from C code using doxygen

Tags: plugins, doxygen, graphviz, flowchart

I'm new to Doxygen, 
I have few doubts regarding this-

1. Can we generate flowchart from C code using Doxygen?
2. If yes, Is there any plugin required? Actually i installed GraphViz for CallGraph.
3. If any relevant link for generating flowchart using Doxygen please share here?
4. If No, Is there any tool will generate both documentation as well as flowchart using C code?

Please answer me if you know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't generate  [flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart)s. **Flowcharts are useless today** (because any real-world program has a too big flowchart). Since the 1960s we use [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) to avoid the need of flowcharts (in practice they are useless since too big). So, even if you generate it, it is unreadable (that is why you don't need it)

Comment: So it seems that your question is really some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is the actual issue you have? Why do you need to generate flowcharts? For whom? Please edit your question to improve it. Otherwise, it is too broad.

Comment: Yes , Actually i'm going to develop a automation tool for documentation for that i need some basic tool like this.?

Comment: It is not a basic tool, and as I explain in my answer, it is completely useless. Don't lose your time on that (and certainly not for documentation)

Comment: okay thanks for giving some hints and suggestion @Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: An external package "Moritz" (https://sourceforge.net/projects/moritz/) exists that can create flowcharts based on doxygen results.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @albert, we can generate a flowchart using C code. Below is the link for the complete procedure to generate a flowchart from C code and other languages which are mentioned below.

https://sourceforge.net/p/moritz/discussion/572218/thread/6fad0579/?limit=25#4e46

Moritz is an "add-on" to the well-known tool Doxygen. It generates Nassi Shneiderman diagrams of functions and methods in a C/C++ source as HTML files, which could be included in a software-documentation or simply can be viewed by using an HTML browser.

Features offered by Moritz are:

1. Moritz is an "add-on" to the well known tool Doxygen.
2. Moritz supports the generation of diagrams like Nassi Shneiderman or UML like activity diagrams.
3. Usable for many programming-languages like C/C++, Python, Matlab or Pascal
4. As console-application Moritz may be used as one tool in a chain of tools controlled by batch or shell-script
5. Detailed configuration by additional XML file.

STEP 2:

Configuration setup is mandatory to generate a DOT file.

STEP 3:

We can generate a flowchart from a DOT file using Graphviz.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Doxygen don't generate [flowcharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart). **Flowcharts are useless today** because they are always too big to be readable (they have been used in the 1950s and 1960s, when computers and programs where a lot smaller). Any practical program has a flowchart with at least thousands of nodes, and that is unreadable so useless.

Since the 1960s we use [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) to avoid the need of flowcharts. Remember Dijkstra's 1968 paper [*Go to considered harmful*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful)

Notice a few things: a lot of simple C macros are corresponding to some subpart (larger than a single node) of flowcharts.

You might perhaps want the [control flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph). But even that is too big to be readable (so in practice you could need some zooming facilities on it). You don't need this CFG, because in practice it is too big also.

You could develop your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to generate the control flow graph (or some kind of flowchart), but (because C has a preprocessor, and that explains why Doxygen cannot generate it reliably) you need to generate it inside your compiler. That could take several months of your time to code such a GCC plugin, and the resulting graph is likely to be too big to stay readable (so should certainly not appear in a user documentation). So in practice you should not lose your time in developing such a useless tool.

But **you don't need to generate flowcharts** (they are unreadable in practice).

If your documentation needs a flowchart, then your code is designed wrong. To explain some code, consider writing [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) in your documentation. Or use higher-level concepts (e.g. [automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory), [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), etc...). At most (but this is generally useless) add some *very simplified* flowchart in your documentation (then, of course you need to draw that idealized flowchart yourself).

Comment: i agreed, But it's customer requirement

Comment: Then you need to discuss with your customer to explain this to him and understand what he *really* needs (my guess is that he does not need a flowchart, but something else, perhaps a grossly simplified flowchart that should not be automatically extracted from source code, but drawn manually...). Otherwise, whatever you painfully produce won't satisfy him

Comment: But generating a flowchart from a real-size program takes months of work (and the result is useless)

Comment: An external package "Moritz" (https://sourceforge.net/projects/moritz/) exists that can create flowcharts based on doxygen results.

Comment: @albert: Moritz is documented to generate "nassi shneiderman diagramms of functions and methods", and these are *not* flowcharts (but something close to CFG)

Comment: When looking at the site of Moritz: https://sourceforge.net/projects/moritz/ and looking at the project samples (middle one), this looks to me like a flow chart.

Comment: can you tell me how can i use Moritz in doxygen tool @albert

Comment: @EasiTest I, recently, didn't try Moritz as I didn't need it, but I think on the Moritz pages there might be some help (see also https://sourceforge.net/p/moritz/wiki/Home/ )